# zeppelin imported classes not found when using

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I get a weird error when using spark on zeppelin. The imported classes are not found when I use them. The code sample is :

```
%spark
import java.io.Serializable
import java.text.{ParseException, SimpleDateFormat}
import java.util.{Calendar, SimpleTimeZone}

class Pos(val pos: String) extends Serializable {

if (pos.length != 12) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"[${pos}] seems not a valid pos 
 string")
}

private val cstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
private val utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
import java.io.Serializable
import java.text.{ParseException, SimpleDateFormat}
import java.util.{Calendar, SimpleTimeZone}
<console>:17: error: not found: type SimpleDateFormat
     private val cstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
                                 ^
<console>:18: error: not found: type SimpleDateFormat
     private val utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
                                 ^
<console>:25: error: not found: type ParseException
       case e: ParseException => throw newIllegalArgumentException(s"
               ^
```

Is there any method to solve the error? 
The zeppelin version is 0.7.3 and spark version is 2.1
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to write imports within class definition :

```
%spark
class Pos(val pos: String) extends Serializable {

    import java.io.Serializable
    import java.text.{ParseException, SimpleDateFormat}
    import java.util.{Calendar, SimpleTimeZone}

    if (pos.length != 12) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"[${pos}] seems not a valid pos string")
    }

    private val cstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
    private val utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
}
```

If you need your imports for the arguments of your class constructor you can create your class within an object and then call `YourObject.YourClass(args)` in the Following paragraphs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168304/zeppelin-with-spark-interpreter-ignores-imports-declared-outside-of-class-functi/52433402#52433402) for another example.

Answer (score 0):

In Zeppelin, you have to import everything on the same line, separating with ; to make it work:

```
import java.io.Serializable; import java.text.{ParseException, SimpleDateFormat}; import java.util.{Calendar, SimpleTimeZone}; class Pos(val pos: String) extends Serializable {

if (pos.length != 12) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"[${pos}] seems not a valid pos 
 string")
}

private val cstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
private val utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
}
```