# Zeppelin with Spark interpreter ignores imports declared outside of class/function definition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, import, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to use some Scala code in Zeppelin 0.8.0 with Spark interpreter:

```
%spark
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

class Node(@BeanProperty val parent: Option[Node]) {
}
```

But imports do not seem to be taken into account

```
import scala.beans.BeanProperty
<console>:14: error: not found: type BeanProperty
                  @BeanProperty val parent: Option[Node]) {
                   ^
```

**EDIT:** I found out that the following code works :

```
class Node(@scala.beans.BeanProperty val parent: Option[Node]) {
}
```

This also works fine :

```
def loadCsv(CSVPATH: String): DataFrame = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    //[...] some code
    val schema = StructType(
        firstRow.map(s => StructField(s, StringType))
    )
    //[…] some code again
}
```

So I guess everything works fine if it is imported between braces or directly specified with a `path.to.package.Class` when used.

**QUESTION:** How do I import outside of a class/function definition?

Comment: which zeppelin version do you use ?

Comment: I use Zeppelin 0.8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (on a VM VirtualBox, but I do not think that is relevant). Spark version is 2.3.1 and JDK 1.8.0_181.

Comment: I found [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49936710/9639861), but it is not answered either. Leaving it there juste in case one of them gets answered.

Comment: [Another link with the same question again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52076014/9639861)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing by `path.to.package.Class` works well in Zeppelin. You can try it with importing and using `java.sql.Date`;

```
import java.sql.Date
val date = Date.valueOf("2019-01-01")
```

The problem is about **Zeppelin context**. If you try to use following code snippets in Zeppelin, you will see that it works fine;

```
object TestImport {
     import scala.beans.BeanProperty
     class Node(@BeanProperty val parent: Option[Node]){}
}
val testObj = new TestImport.Node(None)
testObj.getParent
//prints Option[Node] = None
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: My point is that when the arguments of a class definition need some imports, I can't import within class definition nor outside, I have to specify all imports as I introduce each argument.

Comment: So the only way around to solve this is to define some kind of factory object that creates class instances like in your example?

Comment: As you have already pointed out, we need to use some kind of wrapper object/class to conserve imports like `scala.beans.BeanProperty`. I will try to figure out another way, maybe we can add this as an issue to [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ZEPPELIN/summary)